# TimeLine in google visualisation dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, bind, annotatedtimeline

I have this JSON code:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"ID","type":"number"},
         {"label":"Naziv","type":"string"},
         {"label":"Vrsta","type":"string"},
         {"label":"Status","type":"string"},
         {"label":"Opis","type":"string"},
         {"label":"Pocetak","type":"date"},
         {"label":"Zavrsetak","type":"date"},
         {"label":"Odgovoran","type":"string"},
         {"label":"Parcela","type":"string"},
         {"label":"Usluzno?","type":"string"},
         {"label":"id_parcele","type":"string"}],
 "rows":[{"c":[{"v":1},{"v":"Priprema"},
               {"v":"navodnjavanje"},
               {"v":"U pripremi"},
               {"v":"Da se izrzi nadovdnjavanje"},
               {"v":"Date(2014, 02, 25)"},
               {"v":"Date(2014, 02, 28)"},
               {"v":"Laza Lazic"},
               {"v":"Njiva 5"},
               {"v":"NE"},
               {"v":"0"}]},
         {"c":[{"v":2},
               {"v":"Djubrenje"},
               {"v":"djubrenje"},
               {"v":"U toku"},
               {"v":"Vrsi se djubrenje parcele na temp. od oko 12C"},
               {"v":"Date(2014, 02, 28)"},
               {"v":"Date(2014, 03, 05)"},
               {"v":"Pera Peric"},
               {"v":"vocnjak 3"},
               {"v":"DA"},
               {"v":"0"}]},
         {"c":[{"v":34},
               {"v":"Hemijska analiza"},
               {"v":"odrzavanje, navodnjavanje, "},
               {"v":"U toku"},
               {"v":"Da se izvrsi hemijska analiza"},
               {"v":"Date(2013, 04, 25)"},
               {"v":"Date(2013, 04, 30)"},
               {"v":""},
               {"v":"Vocnjak N, Moja parcela N, "},
               {"v":""},
               {"v":"3, 11, "}]},
         {"c":[{"v":25},
               {"v":"sklas"},
               {"v":"obrada tla, zastita, skladistenje"},
               {"v":"U planu"},
               {"v":"testiranje"},
               {"v":"Date(2013, 04, 17)"},
               {"v":"Date(2013, 04, 30)"},
               {"v":""},
               {"v":"Vocnjak N, S4, Moja parcela N, Parcela 3n "},
               {"v":""},
               {"v":"3, 19, 11, 13"}]}
]}
```

So "Pocetak" and "Zavrsetak" is a Date type. (Start - End dates). I try with this code below to show TimeLine.

CODE:

```
var timeline = new google.visualization.TimeLine({
    'chartType': 'TimeLine',
    'containerId': 'chart5',
    'cssClassNames': 'cssClassNames',
    'options': {
         cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
         allowHtml: true
    }
});
```

and offcource bind timeline:

```
bind([categoryPicker, stringFilter, stringFilter1, slider], [table, timeline]).
```

but dont work, also I dont get any error. Just I dont see anything, no table, no timeline. Witout timeline code all works fine. How to solve this. How to show timeline with objects?

Comment: I just get this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function zadaci.js:101
drawVisualization

Comment: I got this error: Error: First column must contain date, or date and time.

Comment: Yes but I get this JSON from database, how to tranform to work with timeline?

Comment: I see google examples for Timeline, there is no date on first column ...

Comment: Well im not sure which is your column order with that  json, would help if you had a working chart without loading from json

Comment: oh sorry, had read the tag annotated time line but you are looking for a timeline chart

Comment: my current problem is :  undefined is not a function, what that means? also my code work well witout timeline ... so work well with just table

Comment: yes I looking for Timeline chart :) I update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use a ChartWrapper, not a Timeline object:

```
var timeline = new google.visualization.TimeLine(...);
```

should be:

```
var timeline = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(...);
```

Then you need to set the columns to use for the Timeline in the ChartWrapper's `view.columns` parameter:

```
var timeline = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    containerId: 'chart5',
    options: {
         // these options don't do anything in the Timeline chart
         cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
         allowHtml: true
    },
    view: {
        // as an example, use columns "Naziv", "Vrsta", "Pocetak", and "Zavrsetak" for the timeline
        columns: [1, 2, 5, 6]
    }
});
```